# Bleeds inside an artwork (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production, bleed

I'm doing layout design for an LP cover and the record label insists to have print ready PDFs and .psd files, making use of a template they provided. They also want 3mm bleeds along the lines of the artwork inside the template. Now I know how to add bleeds to the document edges, but I'm struggling to understand how to add bleeds in the middle of the artwork?

Here's a screenshot. What I mean is that they want bleeds inside that template that depicts a foldout of an LP cover.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the artwork.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine that bleeds would be *inside* an artwork is when the final artwork has holes cut into it. I'd contact the printer to clarify, if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

The bleed needs to go 3mm over the edge of the cut lines.  It says so on your template.

So for example, if the entire finished work is to be overprinted in blue, drop some guides 3mm from the cut edges, and draw your filled blue shape using these. This is only a rough example, you can measure it accurately using the rulers, but I'm sure you get the general idea.

[image]

Comment: This is correct.  I will also add, that in most cases, 3mm is the minimum amount of bleed they require but you can usual go beyond if you're in a rush or make it easier in some cases. So in the above example you can put a big rectangle around the whole thing if you have a background that spans the whole layout. I will say, what @Billy Kerr did above is the proper way to do it. It's neat, clean and professional.

Answer (score 0):

- Take a New Doc
- Menu>View>Rulers
- It's Will Visibale in top and side
- after drag to your object how you want it
- After Images>Canvas Size>select (cm/mm) width-3mm,height or choose >canvas extension colour>background/or colour

How I Understand Sorry For That!
Or you Try

- Go to View>New Guide>vertical>Position 3 mm and horizontal>position 3 mm